# How To parse this using GSON?

Tags: java, android, gson

I've tried everything but i can't figure it out what Javabeans i need for this:

```
"poitypes":{
  "2":{
     "name":"Info",
     "icon":"info.png"
  },
  "1":{
     "name":"Toilets",
     "icon":"toilets.png"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

if you are talking about the [GSON](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgoogle-gson%2F&rct=j&q=GSON%20&ei=HCUvTZ2zK4O8lQf16ZT8Cw&usg=AFQjCNGGFFMez8-PfFoEQP93a7eHFY8ssA&sig2=H18rEXOsMZu4X-6jlsi5ZQ&cad=rja) library then you do something like this.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader ( inputstream );
Gson g = new Gson ();
MyResultObject result = g.fromJson ( isr, MyResultObject.class );
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need something like this:

```
public class NamedIcon {
  private String name;
  private String icon;

  NamedIcon() {}

  public NamedIcon(String name, String icon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
  }

  // Getters, equals, hashCode, toString, whatever else
}
```

And then some kind of wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper {
  @SerializedName("1") private NamedIcon one;
  @SerializedName("2") private NamedIcon two;

  // ...
}
```

And then, since your "poitypes" field must itself be part of another JSON object (the snippet you've posted by itself isn't legal JSON), you'd need some class representing that, which would have a field called "poitypes" of type `Wrapper` (or whatever you call it).

Now, if your JSON object can actually contain more named icons (called "3", "4", etc.) then you wouldn't be able to do it quite like this. If those numbers are always going to be sequential, the JSON really ought to be a JSON array rather than an object. If they aren't, you'd need to use a custom `JsonDeserializer` to deserialize that object as a `Map<Integer, NamedIcon>` or some such.